# How to choose between "Results then were" and "Results were then"?

Tags: word-order

During typesetting, my editor made some corrections to my manuscript. Most corrections are related to the word order shown below:

> "Results were then used" --> "Results then were used"
>
> "The results are then published" --> "The results then are published"

Why did the editor make such changes? Where can I learn more about the logic behind these changes.

Comment: If you google "adverb word order", you'll find plenty of advice about where to place adverbs such as "then". You can also search this site (e.g., the ["word-order" tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-order)), because there are questions here about that topic, too. (That being said, I think that your versions are better, although it's hard to say for sure without more context.)

Comment: The first correction would only be correct if 'then' refers to results from a previous occasion, but the question lacks context. This would make the second correction incorrect: perhaps "The results then **were** published". It depends on what is meant by 'then'. In the past, or following next?